# How do i make a collision in pong game in canvas to work?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have tried to make a collision so whenever the ball touches the paddles it will bounce back. but there is a problem that i am stuck with and cant figure it out. the problem is that the ball bounces back not just on the paddle but also over and under it. it bounces over the whole yaxis. i'm new to this so i thought maybe start with a simple game. any help could be helpful. thanks

```
let x = canvas.width / 2
let y = canvas.height / 2
let ballX = 3
let ballY = -3


let player1 = {

    x: 50,
    y: canvas.height / 2.5,
    height: 80,
    width: 15,
    speed: 10

}

function left_paddle() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.rect(player1.x, player1.y, player1.width, player1.height);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill()
}


function draw_ball() {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
    ctx.fillStyle = "white"
    ctx.fill()
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", left)
window.addEventListener("keydown", right)

function left(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 83) {
        player1.y += player1.speed
        if (player1.y + player1.height > canvas.height) {                // left paddle down
            player1.y = canvas.height - player1.height
        }
    } else if (e.keyCode == 87) {
        player1.y -= player1.speed
        if (player1.y < 0) {                                            // left paddle up   
            player1.y = 0
        }
    }
}




function detectCollision() {
    if (y + ballY > canvas.height - radius || y + ballY < radius) {     // top and down
        ballY = -ballY
    }
    if (x + ballX > canvas.width - radius) {   // right and left
        ballX = 0
        ballY = 0
        score1++
        console.log(score1)
    } else if (x + ballX < radius) {
        ballX = 0
        ballY = 0
        score2++
    }
    if (x - radius < (player1.x + player1.width)) {       // left paddle collision
        ballX = - ballX
    }


    if (x + radius > player2.x) {                     // right paddle collision
        ballX = -ballX
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @jabaa how is that not a problem. i dont get it. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't say, it's not a problem. I'm saying this question is missing debugging details. From the link: _"StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story."_

Comment: @jabaa how do you want me to write it. i have tried to solve it myself several times but i just cant make it to work. how can i make in interesting.

Comment: what about if i say"Why does the collision i made make the ball bounce over the whole y axis and not just the paddle?"

Comment: It's described in the link. Add log outputs. Use the debugger to add breakpoints (use conditional breakpoints) and step through the code. Find the exact line that doesn't behave as expected. Create a [mcve]. Don't dump your whole code and ask people to debug it for you.

Comment: @jabaa i tried getting rid of most of the code. but it seems like you want me to remove more. i can try to be more precise. the problem is on the detectCollison function on the third if (left paddle collision). if you want i can make a new post and be more precise

Comment: @jabaa this is my first ever post. so i'm sorry. i will try to do better next time

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the height and `y` position of the paddles. There are 3 cases for collision between ball and paddle:

- top corner
- middle
- bottom corner

Middle:

```
if (x - radius < (player1.x + player1.width) && y <= (player1.y + player1.height) && y >= player1.y)
```

Top corner:

```
if (Math.sqrt((player1.x + player1.width - x) ** 2 + (player1.y - y) ** 2) < radius)
```

Bottom corner:

```
if (Math.sqrt((player1.x + player1.width - x) ** 2 + (player1.y + player1.height - y) ** 2) < radius)
```

There's much space to improve the performance. That's just the basic checks. You shouldn't do these checks in each step, only when the x distance and y distance is small enough. `radius ** 2` is usually better than `Math.sqrt`.

There are whole books only about the topic collision detection.

Comment: How did you figure out the top and down one. i still dont get it

Comment: @NoNameYet Game development requires a background in math and geometry. That's the [Euclidean distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).

Comment: what if i want to share the paddle into 3 pieces. so that it has top, middle and bottom. if it the ball hits the top one it goes 45deg and middle is straight while bottom is -45deg. how will that work. could i for example make a variable name angle which equal to Math.pi/4 and then put it in Math.sin(angle) or Math.cos(angle) or something else

Comment: @NoNameYet Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific programming questions. You asked a question and I answered it. Don't ask follow up questions in comments. You can either ask a new question (currently it's too broad and not specific) or try to ask on a different platform. There are platforms where you can find (paid and free) tutors and mentors for broader support.